# Create a column with ranges, Python

Tags: python, pandas, dfply

My data set is Churn_Modeling:

I am looking to create a column called c_rating with the following ranges: `(<500 -="very poor", 500-600="poor", 601-660="fair", 661-780="good", and >= 780 – "excellent").`

Some example data: with columns in order:

```
RowNumber     CustomerId     Surname    CreditScore     Geography   Gender  Age Tenure    Balance   NumOfProducts   HasCrCard   IsActiveMember  EstimatedSalary Exited
        1       15634602    Hargrave            619       France    Female  42       2          0               1           1                1        101348.88     1
        2       15647311        Hill            608       Spain     Female  41       1   83807.86               1           0                1        112542.58     0
        3       15619304        Onio            502       France    Female  42       8   159660.8               3           1                0        113931.57     1
        4       15701354        Boni            699       France    Female  39       1          0               2           0                0         93826.63     0
        5       15737888    Mitchell            850       Spain     Female  43       2  125510.82               1           1                1          79084.1     0
        6       15574012         Chu            645       Spain     Male    44       8  113755.78               2           1                0        149756.71     1
```

I am working on other code so my library is as follows:

```
from plotnine import *
from dfply import *
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
```

```
a_churn = pd.read_csv("Churn_Modeling.csv")
```

How can I do a case_when (like in R) but python to create this column?

Comment: look into `pandas.cut`

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please give us some sample data to work with.

Comment: Copy the data from the spreadsheet, paste in your question and format as code.  This will allow us to copy/paste.

Comment: @Chris done, the formatting is off a little.

Comment: Still no source data

Comment: how about now @MichaelO

Answer (score 1):

```
df['c_rating'] = pd.cut(df['CreditScore'], bins=[0,500,600,660,780,1000], labels=['very poor','poor','fair','good','excellent'])
```

Checking the output

```
df[['CreditScore','c_rating']]

    CreditScore c_rating
0   619         fair
1   608         fair
2   502         poor
3   699         good
4   850         excellent
5   645         fair
```